# Why timezone('-03',now()) adds 3 hours instead of subtract 3 hours in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I'm using PostgreSQL and I need to get the current time in multiple timezones.

My idea is to save and retrive the UTCs via database, so I'll have something like this:

> `select timezone(stored_utc,now()) from my_table;`

To test this solution, I wrote the following code:

> ```
> select now() as current_now,
>      timezone('+02',now()) as plus2,
>      timezone('0',now())   as utc0,
>      timezone('-02',now()) as minus2,
>      timezone('-03',now()) as minus3;
> ```

and got this results:

> [image: results of the previous code]

### Problem

The problem is that I don't understand why using '-03' adds 3 hours and '+03' subtracts 3 hours.

I checked the pg_timezone_names and I'm using the abbrev of the timezones:

> [image: potgresql timezones]

---

### Current Solution

I still want to understand why using 'UTC-3' or '-3' doesn't work. But for now, I'll use the name of the timezones.

> [image: current solution]

Comment: You should *always* use the timezone name, not the offset. Hard-coded offsets change twice a year and the DST rules change whenever a country feels like it. The timezone names don't. If you hard-code the offset in your code you'll have to change it every 6 months for every possible combination. And keep track of when eg Russia will change its DST rules (it's done so a couple of times in the past few years).

Comment: Worse, if you store offsets, you have no idea what *timezone* they refer to. Different countries have different DST rules so times with the same offset in winter won't have the same offset in summer. By storing just the offset you lose the timezone information and the ability to adjust the offset

Comment: The reason is [POSIX time zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html): *The positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich. (Note that this is the opposite of the ISO-8601 sign convention used elsewhere in PostgreSQL.)*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, your arguments will help me to improve my current solution

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver This is the explanation I was looking for!!

Comment: FYI, it was also the answer in the duplicate question link in the closed box. Which I just realized was an answer from me also.